# build.xml README doesn't exist

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, lucene

I have those ant buildfiles below.

[Ant Buildfiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9tTf.jpg)

I am trying to open them but I get some errors. For example when I try to open help I get this error below:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MObgR.jpg)

Do you have any idea how is this fixed ?
Thanks in regard!

Comment: Welcome to the community. I would like to mention that your question is a litle bit unclear. When you said you are trying to open the build files, did you mean that you were trying to run the build files? Also can you share the snippets of the build file? Maybe the initial few lines would suffice. I see an error on line 3 which refers to a README file. Probably that is missing in the directory. If you can share the build file's snippets, it might help us in debugging. Thanks,
Robin

Comment: You can click the error message to navigate to the line where the Ant script fails.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.